# How to link routes list with store variable?

Tags: vue.js, routes, vuex

Is there any way to link routes list:

```
// router.js
export default new Router({
   routes: [
      { path: '/', component: Page },
      { path: '/page1', component: Page1 },
      { path: '/page2', component: Page2 },
   ]
})
```

...to the variable in store:

```
// store.js
export default new Vuex.Store({
   state: {
      routes_list: []
   }
})
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a getter for your list. Something like:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
   state: {
      routes_list: []
   },
  getters: {
    routesList: state => {
      return state.routes_list;
    }
  }
})
```

Then you could import your Store in your router.js and use the created getter to receive the list:

```
// maybe your path is different
import Store from '@/store/index';
export default new Router({
   routes: Store.getters.routesList
})
```

I've didn't tested the router code, maybe you need to do some correction.